# Error(12,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored Error(12,15): PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context

Tags: oracle

I've written a condition in a Stored PROCEDURE as the following:

```
IF (ISBN_in IN (SELECT ISBN FROM ADD_BOOK))
/*Checking whether ISBN_in value exists in ADD_BOOK table or not*/
THEN

   UPDATE ADD_BOOK
   SET TITLE=TITLE_in,
   ADD_SUMMARY=Add_Summary_in,
   AUTHOR=Author_in,
   Published_Date=Published_Date_in,
   PAGE_COUNT=Page_Count_in 
   WHERE 
   ISBN=ISBN_IN;
   COMMIT;
END IF;

There, I'm seeing an error message as 

Error(12,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(12,16): PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
```

Please advice further.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [if (select count(column) from table) > 0 then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200281/if-select-countcolumn-from-table-0-then)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could remove the if statement altogether and attempt the update anyway:

UPDATE add_book
SET ...
WHERE isbn = isbn_in;

If there are no rows to update, nothing happens. You've also saved yourself an extra call to the table, so your code will be a bit more performant.