# How to pass a count as IF condition on ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, count

i want to use a COUNT result as IF CONDITION on ORACLE, like this pseudocode on oracle:

```
select count(d.number_people) as counted_people
from dual d
if counted_people = 1 then
dbms_output.put_line('Have just one people on this column.'
end if;
```

This syntax is wrong, I know, how do I do it the right way?

Comment: [DUAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table) is a special one-row one-colum table, and it does not have `number_people` column, It's not clear what number of people do you want to count from this table using `SELECT count(number_people) FROM dual` ?

Comment: Its a example , the ploblem is how to use a count as if statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if (select count(column) from table) > 0 then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200281/if-select-countcolumn-from-table-0-then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SELECT ... INTO variable ...`
Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=610d02797857539be5fcd4afdbd7d9e6

```
DECLARE 
  cnt number;
BEGIN
  select count(*) INTO cnt from dual;
  IF cnt = 1 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exaclty one record');
  ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('0 or more than 1  record');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` is an aggregation result. You can count all rows in a table, all rows that match certain criteria, etc. As an aggregation result, you can use it in the `SELECT` clause, in the `HAVING` clause, and in the `ORDER BY` clause. (You cannot use it in the `WHERE` clause, because the `WHERE` clause deals with the data in the table rows. You need a `HAVING` clause instead, which deals with aggregation results.)

**SELECT clause / ORDER BY clause example**

```
select
  supplier_id,
  case when count(*) < 20 then 'less then 20 orders'
       when count(*) < 40 then 'less beteen 20 and 40 orders'
       else '40 or more orders'
  end as number_of_orders
from orders
where order_date >= date '2018-01-01'
group by supplier_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

**HAVING clause example**

```
select sex, count(*)
from members
group by sex
having count(*) > 20;
```

Comment: I have been doing Oracle since v4 (1985), and this is the first time I have seen this group by clause.

Comment: My comment was supposed to be a joke because of the particular column you are grouping by.

Comment: @Roger Cornejo: Ah, sorry. Yeah, I must admit when typing my query I wondered for a moment if the `BY` in `GROUP BY` was optional ;-)

Comment: :-)) hilarious :-))