# How to inline a recordtype variable during a procedure call?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a `SELECT` statement directly as a stored procedure parameter, but I'm unable to. If I add a local variable and `Select` `INTO` it, it works fine.

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE
    something MyTable%ROWTYPE;
    PROCEDURE Test(param IN MyTable%ROWTYPE) as
    BEGIN
        ...
    END;
BEGIN
    SELECT 
      SYS_GUID() as ID,
      'X' as COLUMN1,
      'Y' as COLUMN2,
      'Z' as COLUMN3
      INTO something
      FROM DUAL
      WHERE rownum < 2;

    Test(something);
END;
```

This works fine as expected, but if I attempt to inline the `something` variable, it fails:

```
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE Test(param IN MyTable%ROWTYPE) as
    BEGIN
        ...
    END;
BEGIN
    Test((SELECT 
      SYS_GUID() as ID,
      'X' as COLUMN1,
      'Y' as COLUMN2,
      'Z' as COLUMN3
      FROM DUAL
      WHERE rownum < 2));
END;
```

> ORA-06550: line 11, column 11:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( - + case mod new not null 
>       
>      continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
>      sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
>      date 
>        pipe
>
> - & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem  and
>     or group having intersect minus order start union where
>     connect || multiset

Why does it not accept my inline select statement but works when storing the result into a variable? What do I need to do to allow the inline statement to work as I intend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle cannot [directly use SQL statements in PL/SQL expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10203109/409172).  (Although it is possible in Postgres and possibly other database systems.)

If you want to pass SQL statements around it might be easier to use `SYS_REFCURSOR`, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(id varchar2(32), x varchar2(1), y varchar2(1), z varchar2(1));

DECLARE
    v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

    something MyTable%ROWTYPE;
    PROCEDURE Test(p_cursor sys_refcursor) as
    BEGIN
        FETCH p_cursor INTO something;
        dbms_output.put_line(something.id);
    END;
BEGIN
    OPEN v_cursor for
    SELECT 
        SYS_GUID() as ID,
        'X' as COLUMN1,
        'Y' as COLUMN2,
        'Z' as COLUMN3
        INTO something
        FROM DUAL;

    Test(v_cursor);
END;
/
```

Comment: I assume you don't need `INTO something` on the `SELECT` statement anymore with this approach.

Comment: @julealgon That is correct.  Although eventually you will need to use `INTO something` with the cursor variable.